# upload Laravel in subfolder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have uploaded my `public` items in `public_html/demo`

other folders to `/home/danior/source/`

---

/home/danior/public_html/demo/index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../source/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../source/bootstrap/app.php';
```

---

/home/danior/source/server.php:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/demo/index.php';
```

---

http://danior.ir/demo/
but there some unknown errors !

filesystem.php won't upload

Comment: checked on `bootstrap/app.php` yet? set the real path?

Comment: @BagusTesa ```$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
); ``` where should it be set ? while my index.php is in /public_html/demo/index.php

Comment: wah, sorry, that thing perhaps.. could you share the location of the public and the source? because `/../` denotes relative location. sorry for misleading you into checking `app.php`, the thing should be changed only `index.php` indeed.

Comment: @BagusTesa it is set to `/home/danior/source`

Answer (score 0):

I upload my projects like this, hope it will help-

1. Create a sub-domain/domain eg- `demo`
2. Upload public folder items in your sub-domain "`demo`".
3. Create another folder inside public_html eg- `demo_support`.
4. Compress rest of the files as `xyz.tar` and upload and decompress in `public_html/demo_support` and configure your `.env` according to you.
5. Now in your `public_html/demo/index.php` -

replace

**`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`**

with

**`require __DIR__.'/../demo_support/bootstrap/autoload.php';`**

and

replace

**`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`**

with

**`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../demo_support/bootstrap/app.php';`**

Comment: the problem is with `filesystem.php won't upload`

Comment: compress vendor folder as .tar and  then try to upload it

Comment: the hosting antivirus has removed Filesystem.php